# htaccess RewriteRule to directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to make a redirect from this url:
`http://www.mywebsite.it/it/component/fss/?view=admin_support`
to this url:
`http://www.mywebsite.it/it/index.php/component/fss/?view=admin_support`

Attempts with modifying the .htaccess file with `RewriteRule` (shown below) have failed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/fss/(.*)$ index.php/component/fss/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Is **/it** an existent directory?

Comment: yes it's a existent directory

Comment: Try adding this line **DirectoryIndexRedirect On** to your **/it/.htaccess**

Comment: On the httpdocs folder, not in /it

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, it is about redirecting your folder index and not related.

Comment: Moved the .htaccess inside /it/ but don't work

Comment: Are there other rules as well in your .htaccess?

Comment: No, only the RewriteRule